# How can I sort 4 seperate string arrays (with the same lenght), according to one of them in alphabetical order? (in C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have read out per WMI the installed programs on a remote PC. I have read the Program Name, Program Publisher, Program Install.date and Program install.path properties and stored each of them in a separate string array. (All arrays with same length: 99)

I want to list the program informations according to the alphabetical order of Program name.
Is it possible to do that without combining the 4 arrays in one multidimensional array?
Or should I first combine the arrays to one two dimensional array ?
If yes how?

As I am new in C# I would thank you if you would make a suggestion. I have read lots of entries but I got more confused.

```
    public string[] Programs_WMI_name = new string[99];
    public string[] Programs_WMI_publisher = new string[99];
    public string[] Programs_WMI_installdate = new string[99];
    public string[] Programs_WMI_installlocation = new string[99];
```

I have tried this but get error:

In my public Class

```
    public class TagService{
    public string Programs_WMI_Name { get; set; }
    public string Programs_WMI_Publisher { get; set; }
    public string Programs_WMI_Installdate { get; set; }
    public string Programs_WMI_Installlocation { get; set; }
    public List<string> programs = new List<string>(99);
    }
```

then

```
    for (int i = 0; i < TagService.Programs_WMI_name.Length; i++)
            {
                programs.Add(new TagService
                {
                    Programs_WMI_Name = TagService.Programs_WMI_name[i],
                    Programs_WMI_Publisher = TagService.Programs_WMI_publisher[i],
                    Programs_WMI_Installdate = TagService.Programs_WMI_installdate[i],
                    Programs_WMI_Installlocation = TagService.Programs_WMI_installlocation[i],
                });
            }
            programs = programs.OrderBy(p => p.Programs_WMI_Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make classes to represent the objects and the sort a single list of class instances?

Comment: In your updated code, your TagService class has a "programs" field that you do *not* want there (that class shouldn't care about how many instances are created, plus it's a list of strings). The "programs" you are adding a new TagService instance to (your last code fragment) should be a `List<TagService>`

Answer (score 5):

Do yourself and others a favor and use classes

```
public class ProgramInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public string InstallDate { get; set; }
    public string InstallLocation { get; set; }
}
```

from arrays

```
var programs = new List<ProgramInfo>(Programs_WMI_name.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < Programs_WMI_name.Length; i++)
{
    programs.Add(new ProgramInfo
    {
            Name = Programs_WMI_name[i],
            Publisher = Programs_WMI_publisher[i],
            InstallDate = Programs_WMI_installdate[i],
            InstallLocation = Programs_WMI_installlocation[i],
    });
}
```

better yet fill from query directly

```
var programs = new List<ProgramInfo>();
foreach (var row in new ManagementObjectSearcher(somequery).Get())
{
    programs.Add(new ProgramInfo
    {
        Name = row["name"],
        Publisher = row["publisher"],
        InstallDate = row["installdate"],
        InstallLocation = row["installlocation"],
    });
}
```

complete example could look like this

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public class ProgramInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public string InstallDate { get; set; }
        public string InstallLocation { get; set; }
    }

    public class TagService
    {
        public static List<ProgramInfo> Programs { get; } = new List<ProgramInfo>();

        public static void RefreshPrograms()
        {
            Programs.Clear();
            foreach (var row in new ManagementObjectSearcher(somequery).Get())
            {
                programs.Add(new ProgramInfo
                {
                    Name = row["name"],
                    Publisher = row["publisher"],
                    InstallDate = row["installdate"],
                    InstallLocation = row["installlocation"],
                });
            }
            Programs.Sort((l, r) => string.Compare(l.Name, r.Name));
        }
    }

    public Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            TagService.ReadPrograms();
            var properties = typeof(ProgramInfo).GetProperties();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", properties.Select(p => p.Name.PaddRight(10))));
            foreach (var program in TagService.Programs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", properties.Select(p => ((string)p.GetValue(program)).PaddRight(10))));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mdarende if possible, do not first fill arrays, then use this, but try to fill this ProgramInfo class (and list) immediately when you get the info from WMI for each program

Comment: @Firo One question to your solution: I have to create the list as a public list. If a declare it as public List<string> programs = new List<string>(); I get error in my code. How can I correct this?

Comment: @Mdarende we can't see your code nor the error. My code creates the list as a local variable in the function/constructor whatever. Assign the list to your public property.

Comment: @Firo  I have added my code in my question. I get error when using public List. Sorry I am a beginner, therefore it can be shameful what I have done.

Comment: @Mdarende no problem that you are a beginner. But when you get "an error" then it would help us if you specify *what* error